# How to structure NoSQL Documents in Azure for Lookup By Array of String contains?

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb

NoSQL newbie here..

I have `Employee` documents and every `Employee` has a `name` and has one to many `tag`s. Here is a possible representation of an `employee` object in JSON format:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "tags": ["blue", "red", "green"]
}
```

I want to be able to query `Employee` instances in Cosmos DB by their `tag`s. For example, I want to find an `Employee` where `tags contains 'green'`. An `Employee` will not have too many tags, maybe up to 10 or 15 at most.

What is the best way to model the document structure for this use case? [cosmos db documentation here](https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/03-querying_in_azure_cosmosdb.html#dot-and-quoted-property-projection-accessors) suggests a structure akin to following for a reason I do not understand:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "blue"
    },
    {
      "name": "red"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any reason to split a String array into child JSON objects like this?

Answer (score 1):

How to model documents is totally based on your requirement, there is no strict rule for that.

For your doc structure, I did some test on my side and this all my test doc,4 docs in total:
[image]

I can use the query below to find out all employees that contain the "green" tag:

```
SELECT c.name,c.tags FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.tags, "green")
```

[image]

Comment: True, my question is, given I will have millions of records and almost always I will be querying by color.. What is the _best practice_ in a NoSQL(CosmosDB to be more specific) environment?

Comment: Hi @KorayTugay, your model is ok here. For cosmos DB,  the point that will greatly affect query performance is the partition key. For details about it, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey

Comment: @KorayTugay if you are almost always querying by color, then wouldn't make sense to replicate the data in a new collection partitioned by color? As per the guidelines, storage is much cheaper than RUs.